# Proof of $\alpha^+ = \alpha +1$ for Ordinal $\alpha$

Tags: ordinals

Let $\alpha$ be ordinal number.

I want to prove that $\alpha^+ = \alpha +1$.

Is it sufficient for me to follow below listed steps?

first, since $\alpha$ is a well-ordered set, we can define the summation of natural numbers.

second, then since $\alpha^+ = \alpha \cup \{\alpha\}$, it equals to $\alpha +1$

Comment: Once you state what the order is on $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ and $\alpha+1$, it is automatic.

Comment: @ziggurism what makes me little bit hesistant is since I had define $\alpha \cup \{\alpha\} = \alpha +1$ only in case of $\alpha$ is natural number, then shouldn't I have to show that $\alpha$ is natural number ?

Comment: If you want to prove the result only for $\alpha$ a natural number, then you don't have to prove that $\alpha$ is a natural number, you can just assume it by hypothesis. On the other hand, if you want to prove the result for $\alpha$ any ordinal, then you do not need to make that assumption. But the statement $\alpha+1 = \alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ holds for all $\alpha.$

Comment: hum.. that means all ordinals inherit the operation defined in $\Bbb N$?

Comment: Regarding notation: It is usual that $a^+$ denotes the least cardinal ordinal greater than $a,$ not the ordinal successor of $a.$ What you are looking for is a proof that there are no ordinals between $a$ and $a+1$ in the  $\in$-order. We have $a^+=a+1$ iff $a\in \omega,$ that is,iff $a$ is a finite ordinal. Set-theorists often consider the finite ordinals and the non-negative integers to be the same things, but ordinals  altogether include much more things.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thx. finite ordinals often considred to be the same thing with non-negative integers.. okay got it.

Answer (score 1):

A set is a transitive set iff every member of it is a subset of it.

A set is an ordinal iff it is a transitive set which is well-ordered by $\in.$ A well-order on a set  $S$ is an irreflexive linear order $<$ on $S$ such that whenever $\phi\ne T\subseteq S$ there is a unique  $<$-least member of $T.$ The class of ordinals is usually denoted by $On.$ Some basic properties of ordinals:

(i). If $a, b\in On$ and $a\ne b$ then $a\in b$ or $b\in a.$ Note that it follows from $b$ being  a  transitive set that $a\in b\implies a\subset b.$

(ii).   If $x\in y\in On$ then $x\in On.$ That is, the members of an ordinal (if any) are ordinals.

(iii). If $x\in On$ then $x\not \in x.$ Without the Axiom of Foundation (a.k.a. Regularity) we can consistently assume there exists a set $A$ with $A\in A,$ but such an  $A $ cannot be an ordinal.

(iv).  Any set of ordinals is linearly ordered by $\in.$

For your Q: If $a,b\in On$ and $a<b$ then $a\in b$ by def'n of $<$ for $On.$ Also $b$ is a transitive set so $a\in b\implies a\subset b.$ Hence $a\cup \{a\}\subset b.$

By (iv) we have $a\cup \{a\}\ne a.$ Hence by (i) we have $a<a+1$. We have $a<a+1=a\cup \{a\}\subset b.$ Therefore $a<a+1\leq b.$

REMARKS. We can define "finite ordinal"  in several ways without the word "finite". E.g. $x\in On$ and $x$ is doubly well-ordered: Every non-empty $T\subset x$ has a $\in$-largest  member as well as a  $\in$-least member..... With the Axiom of Infinity we can show there exists the set $\omega\;$ ("\omega") of all finite ordinals, which is also the least infinite ordinal.